# Flask API issue

Tags: api, flask, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

Main.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
import json
import string
import random
import os


# load the tokenizer and label encoder
with open('tokenizer.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer_from_json(data)

with open('label_encoder.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.classes_ = np.array(data)

with open('responses.json') as file:
    responses = json.load(file)

# load the trained model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['POST'])
def chatbot():

        # get user input
        data = request.get_json()
        texts_p = []
        prediction_input = data['input']

        # preprocess the input
        prediction_input = [letters.lower() for letters in prediction_input if letters not in string.punctuation]
        prediction_input = ''.join(prediction_input)
        texts_p.append(prediction_input)
        prediction_input = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts_p)
        prediction_input = np.array(prediction_input).reshape(-1)
        prediction_input = pad_sequences([prediction_input], maxlen=18)

        # get the output from the model
        output = model.predict(prediction_input)
        output = output.argmax()

        # find the tag and select a response
        response_tag = le.inverse_transform([output])[0]
        response = random.choice(responses[response_tag])

        # return the response
        return jsonify({'response': response})


port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

This is my Flask API which works correctly when i run on local host and when i try to deploy it on gcloud it gives an error after deployment. I have all the required file like, app.yaml and requirments.txt. When i try to use the URL (provided by gcloud after deployment) in a demo created website(also in separate flask)

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python39

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

handlers:
- url: /chatbot
  script: auto

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  secure: always
  script: auto

env_variables:
  TOKENIZER_PATH: "tokenizer.json"
  LABEL_ENCODER_PATH: "label_encoder.json"
  RESPONSES_PATH: "responses.json"
  MODEL_PATH: "my_model.h5"
```

Flask for sending request and taking output(response):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

chatbot_api_url = 'https://al-siraj-380904.uc.r.appspot.com/chatbot'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.form['user_input']
        response = requests.post(chatbot_api_url, json={'input': user_input})
        chatbot_response = response.json()['response']
    else:
        chatbot_response = ''
    return render_template('index.html', chatbot_response=chatbot_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this same flask website works perfectly with the same flask API on local host.
these are the pictures of error:
01: enter input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRd2T.png)
02: when you click 'send'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cehtV.png)

i have tried everything i could found. can anyone guide me thoroughly. help will be appreciated.

I tried changing things here and there in the api code But still i failed.

Comment: Are you sure of your response format?

Comment: Seeing the return statement of the API (return jsonify({'response': response})). It's returning the response in json format. And its working perfectly fine on local host. Is there a separate format for gcloud?

Comment: Can you print on your client side the RAW data  that your receive? (The raw response!)

Comment: I dont know how to send input through a URL. I only request the URL using POST method by small dummy html site to send input and receive output. I modified my flask code yesterday and implemented flask_restful in it so, when i go to "/chatbot" url route it gives me a json display. Is that what you are asking for. But after deployment on gcloud it gives 502 error.

Comment: Now that i think about it I think the error is on deployment not the code. My bad, sorry for your time . And thanks for your time too.